# VBA IFELSE Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an ifelse statement to show that if the text in column B is equal to "Green" then Column C should say "Go". If Column B is equal to "Yellow" then Column C should say "Yield" and if column B is equal to "Red" then Column C should say "Stop"

I was using the below code. The code says it completes but nothing gets populated.

```vba
 If Range("B7:B50").Text = "Green" Then
   Range("C7:C50").Text = "Go"
   ElseIf Range("B7:B50").Text = "Yellow" Then
   Range("C7:C50").Text = "Yield"
   ElseIf Range("B7:B50").Text = "Red" Then
   Range("C7:C50").Text = "Stop"    
 End If
```

Can someone take a look and help me out?

Comment: You will need to loop.  You cannot test equate a range/array to a single text string.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get a generic run-time error with this code.

Comment: ^^^^^ My guess is you have an improper use of `On Error Resume Next` somewhere before this block.  That needs to be removed and the code should be written to deal with the errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner @JNevill: You can use the `Text`-property on a Range that contains more than one cell, however, it will return `Null` in that case.

Comment: @User275: As Scott Craner wrote, you will need to loop as you can check only one cell at a time. You should use the `Value`-property of the cells, not the `Text`-property.